Was the mother of David the same woman as the mother of Jesse's other sons?
The story is outlined here by Robev.
I have certainly seen differing versions, for which I don't have references.
I'm pretty sure I have seen at least one version in which Jesse's sons wish to put the woman (Nazbat/Netzevet) to death. That would be odder if she were their mother.
Also, she would presumably be rather old. I know that's not impossible.
As for their hostility to the pregnancy, and to David, it could be explained if they believe he is not Jesse's child. But I wonder if there is more to it than that.
Similarly, Jesse's "separation" from his wife. I understand he has fears about the halakhah of his ancestor Boaz having taken a Moabite wife. Hence the fear of fathering a non-Israelite. But if he already has sons, why the special concern about this one?
The story, and especially the hostility of the sons, would make more sense if Nazbat were a second wife.
